# How to disable normal behaviour of Alt key?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, keyboard

Normally the Alt key opens the menu in Windows.

I need this to be disabled, because I need Alt key for my application. (It is an emulator of old computer, so I need to mimic its behaviour.) I write it in pure Windows API, so I expect there must be some message which is sent and needs to be disabled, discarded or ignored.

Alt+Tab is no problem, as well as other system keys and key combinations, I just need to ignore Alt when it opens the menu.

(My application uses DirectInput to read the keys, so it works well. I just need to disable the functionality which opens the menu with Alt key. I will open the menu using mouse.)

Comment: What menu is this? I just typed Alt on a Windows box and no menu came up.

Comment: @Kaz: It sets focus to the menu bar of the focused window.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about checking for `WM_SYSCOMMAND`, and when wParam is `SC_KEYMENU`, return 0?

**Update / exact solution:**

```
if(wParam==SC_KEYMENU && (lParam>>16)<=0) return 0;
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
```

Description: If `lParam>>16` is positive then menu is activated by mouse, when it is zero or negative then menu is activated by Alt or Alt+something.

Comment: This helped me to find the right solution. I added the solution to this answer.

Comment: Helped me as well. This problem was so terrible the ALT key and a few other keys on Windows 8 constantly screw with Win32 Applications. Also thanks for the small description it makes understanding what's going on more clear. I never knew what the lParam or wParam were used for before since it never was used too much in my needs.