# SWT issues with cascaded MenuItem accelerators

Tags: java, menu, swt

The MenuItem objects having a **SWT.CASCADE** style (like 'File') won't drop down when the accelerator key combo is pressed.

In the example below, pressing Alt-F triggers the Selection event (I see "File" in the console) but the menu itself won't drop down. I couldn't find a method to programmatically make the menu drop down either. Any idea?

(The package I'm using is org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.100.0.v4233d.jar provided with the current version of Eclipse Juno.)

```
public class MenuTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Menu menu = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);

        MenuItem item = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);
        item.setText("File");
        item.setAccelerator(SWT.ALT | 'F');
        Menu dropMenu = new Menu(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);

        item.setMenu(dropMenu);
        item.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("File");
            }
        });

        item = new MenuItem(dropMenu, SWT.NULL);
        item.setText("Close");
        item.setAccelerator(SWT.ALT | SWT.F4);
        item.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Close");
                shell.dispose();
            }
        });

        shell.setMenuBar(menu);

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: @nick- the **SWT.CASCADE** works for me, though i am on `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.100.0.v4233d.jar` . Could you post a running example?

Comment: The accelerator seems to work, but the menu would not drop down. I've rephrased the question and added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ***`nothing wrong`*** with your code and it is working as expected. By default on Windows OS, the Menu bars receive input focus when users press the Alt key and they lose input focus with the Esc key (see [Keyboard accessibility section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511500.aspx)).

Now an accelerator is like a hot key/combination which is there to make ones life easier. In your scenario, when you press the <kbd>ALT + F</kbd> then default behavior of <kbd>ALT</kbd> of setting focus on the menu is over-ridden. And, that is why the menu listener is fired but the drop down menu is not shown.

#### Possible Solution

1. Instead of `item.setAccelerator(SWT.ALT | 'F');` do something like this `item.setAccelerator(SWT.MOD1 | 'F');`. **Where** `MOD1`, `MOD2` **..** `MOD4` are the keyboard and/or mouse event mask indicating that the MOD1 key was pushed on the keyboard when the event was generated.
2. On Windows OS ***`you need not`*** to set an accelerator for topmost level menu. Instead use `mnemonic`. For example, `item.setText("&File");`. See javadoc of `setText()` for more details.
3. Or, more drastically [How to disable normal behaviour of Alt key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627379/how-to-disable-normal-behaviour-of-alt-key) (its a C++ solution)

#### Result of mnemonic

See the underline under the `F` of `File`.

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks so much. (Also, the ampersand syntax reminds me of the not-so-old Win32 days, and I thought that SWT abstracted that, somehow.)