# SWT popup menu shortcut not working

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am creating an Eclipse plugin and using the SWT popup menu (context menu) for one of the controls in plugin. The context menu item works, but the accelerator (shortcut) that I set for the menu item has no effect and it does not work. I create the menuitem like this:

```
MenuItem parent = new Menu(getShell(), SWT.POP_UP);
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(parent, SWT.PUSH);
menuItem.setText("Click me");
menuItem.setAccelerator( SWT.CTRL+ 'F');
```

Note that the shortcut problem occurs for the `POP_UP` menu, not the `BAR` menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Try `item.setAccelerator(SWT.MOD1 + 'A');`

MOD1, MOD2 .. MOD4 are the keyboard and/or mouse event mask indicating that the MOD1 key was pushed on the keyboard when the event was generated.

More references [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/SetAcceleratorforMenuItem.htm) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219537/swt-issues-with-cascaded-menuitem-accelerators).

**Edit:**

If you are developing an Eclipse plugin, and you are putting the menu on a `View`, then it is possible that the Eclipse Platform shortcut system is interfering with your SWT component's accelerator.

I suggest you refactor your code, so that you use the shortcuts **extension** that Eclipse provides.

Comment: Yes. Im using an eclipse plugin. My plugin has many views(say 10-15) and I have some controls on each of the views that provide some popup menu functionalities. How do I register shortcut for each context menu item?